# Is there a powerful Multiple Calendar Tool out there?

Tags: agile, pm-software, tools

I've looked into many different types of tools, but I'm not finding one that can:

1. Create multiple project calendars
2. See a Master View of All Project calendars
3. Unlimited filtering options for multiple views
4. Tracking dependencies and constraints

I'm not looking for an agile ALM tool, or something like that. Is there a powerful standalone calendar tool out there???

Comment: how about dotproject: http://www.dotproject.net/

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on PMSE. They *may* be on topic at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it will work for your needs, but I use http://tungle.me to consume some calendars and expose it on the web.....can integrate business gmail and personal gmail, etc and it just shows what's blocked off.  I doubt it is what you are looking for, but at the very least it is nice for exposing your personal calendar to other businesses out there(not the details, just the times you are not available).

Comment: is this secure? with ability to do intranet calendar sync?

Answer (score 1):

I maybe do not understand your question properly. But from what you are describing Microsoft Project could work.

Comment: yes... i thought someone would say that. not really. We need a "nice" view of calendars. something easy to consume...

Comment: What to do mean when you say "easy to consume"? What are you trying to do? I may have a tool, but it would be helpful to know more about what your specific needs are.

Comment: Email me about your tool. As for "consume" something easy on the eyes, display-wise...